# How to download local array or add to postgres database

Tags: javascript, arrays, geolocation

I am having a difficult time trying to download arrays of geolocations into my local storage or even better append them to postgres/postgis database. The console at `loc` prints fine, but when i see the geojson downloaded, it is empty. Am I missing anything?

```
var loc= new Array();

//click event for map
map.on("click", function(e){

    //add marker to click location
    var mp = new L.Marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]).addTo(map);

    //alert the location of the place           
    var pos= mp.getLatLng();
    alert(pos);

    apt_loc= new Array();
    apt_loc.push(pos);
    console.log(apt_loc);

    //for each item in apt_loc, add it to loc
    apt_loc.forEach(item=> loc.push(apt_loc));
    console.log(loc);

});
function saveToFile(content, filename) {
      var file = filename + '.geojson';
      saveAs(new File([JSON.stringify(content)], file, {
        type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
      }), file);
    } 

saveToFile(loc,'test');
```

Comment: "but when i see the geojson downloaded, it is empty". How and where are you trying to see the geojson in the code? Is there more code missing where you actually *download* the geojson?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Edited to include the missing code.

Comment: By looking at the code, I think it will always be empty because `loc` is the empty array. Maybe what you should do is bind the `saveToFile` function to an event like a button click. In that way you would be able to click the map to generate locations and then save de file by clicking the "save" button. (The suggestion of a button for saving is just as an example to generate an event posterior to the clicks on the map.)

Comment: @cabesuon the clicks are lat/lng positions on openlayers map, how do I collect the click events and download them using a download button in html. How do I attach the click events to download button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that you can follow. Everything is in an html file to make it easy to test and post. In the example I use the draw interaction to get the points of the map instead of click event. What I try to mention in the comment, is that you were saving the file before getting any point. I added a button as an example of an event posterior to points generation.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
            #a { display: none; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>Download Points</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Click on Map to add Points then Download to file</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <button onclick="downloadPoints()">Download</button>
    <p id="p"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var downloadPoints = function () {
        var file = new Blob([getGeoJSONText()], {type: 'text/plain'});
        if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
        else {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'points.geojson';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.body.removeChild(a);
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
            }, 0); 
        }
    }
    var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});
    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source
    });
    var getGeoJSONText = function () {
        var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
        return format.writeFeatures(
            source.getFeatures(),
            {
                dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
            });
    }
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }),
            vector
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
            zoom: 4
        })
    });
    var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: source,
        type: 'Point'
    });
    draw.on('drawend', function () {
        document.getElementById('p').innerText = getGeoJSONText();
    });
    map.addInteraction(draw);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, You are a blessing!

Comment: Are the methods any different in Leaflet?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that question, I have not use Leaflet much.